Continuous DLT Pipeline does not perform other tasks on further runs
We have a DLT pipeline running in Continuous Mode as the most-upstream table is a Streaming Table.
In one Materialized View running something in the middle of the whole pipeline, we have a few extra tasks apart from the data transformation that we are required to perform (e.g. upsert to delta table, fire an event via REST API):
def transform_data(source_df):
    final_df = source_df.select(
        col("col_a"),
        col("col_b")
    )

    physical_delta_table = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "some_delta_table_name")

    physical_delta_table.alias("target").merge(
        final_df.alias("source"),
        merge_condition
    ).whenMatchedUpdateAll(
        condition=expr(update_condition)
    ).whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
    .execute

    publish_event(EventType.DATA_AVAILABLE)

    return final_df


def buildDataProduct():
    @dlt.table(
        name = "dlt_table_name"
    )
    def table():
        df_source = dlt.read("upstream")
    
        return transform_data(df_source)

This is a high-level overview of how the Delta Live Table works in the pipeline.

During the first run of the pipeline, all three tasks from the Materialized View are being performed.
However, we noticed that when the pipeline runs through this particular script in the next succeeding runs, it successfully processes the Materialized View but doesn't perform the upsert to delta table and the event firing (Yellow Tasks). The Yellow-colored tasks don't execute even if a successful update of the DLT Pipeline has occurred.
Does DLT only preserve the Data Definition and disregards all other operations in its succeeding runs?

Are you calling this function buildDataProduct()

Since uour upstream is streaming,  should your  code be dlt.read_stream("upstream")?

As per this documentation using MERGE INTO can produce incorrect results because of out-of-sequence records or requires complex logic to re-order records.
So, creating a streaming table and do apply_changes to handle changing/updating data.
Also, as @Anupam Chand said you need to read streaming data like dlt.read_stream("upstream") but when you do read dlt.read("upstream") it read the whole upstream table when it is updated.
After doing apply changes use that streaming table as materialized view to fire an event via REST API and apply transform for table c.
Below is the sample code.
dlt.create_streaming_table("target")

dlt.apply_changes(
  target = "target",
  source = "upstreamTable",
  keys = ["userId"],#key column to merge.
  sequence_by = col("sequenceNum"),
  stored_as_scd_type = 1
)

Now, use this target table for creating materialized view and to fire event.
